# Standard split between author and illustrator of children's book

Tags: publishing, children

I know that every case can be different, but it seems like there should be a standard split between the author and the illustrator of a children's book. Does anyone know?

Comment: Is there a website that makes doing these splits easy for newbie illustrator + writer teams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The split is usually 50:50. In a picture book the illustrator may get 60:40.

Answer (score 9):

I am a children's book illustrator. Thom is right 50:50 or for heavily illustrated picture books 60:40. When it comes to the advance, the illustrator usually gets more because it will take them 3 to 8 months to finish illustrations for the book. They need something to live on while they are working.